# Capturar somente a segunda parte da string

Tags: string, vb.net

Tenho o seguinte código para realizar o método `Split` em um caminho:

```
Dim ItemsCopy As Integer = 0


    Dim Caminho As String = ContarItems(I)
    Dim SplitCam As String() = Regex.Split(Caminho.ToString, "=")

    For Each S As String In SplitCam

        Vizualizador.ListBox1.Items.Add(S)
    Next
```

Onde tem o `ContarItems(I)` é um *array* que coloquei em cima só para guarda o URL, mas é o seguinte tenho um URL

```
Exemplo: Victor\junior\Documentos\=Pasta\Teste\arquivo.teste
```

Quando uso o método ele corta certinho e adiciona na `listbox`, mas eu queria que ele só colocasse a segunda parte no caso `Pasta\Teste\arquivo.teste` ele coloca a primeira e a segunda, e não quero essa primeira parte.

Comment: Parece que você está fazendo algo errado.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Me parece simples assim, mas pode ser que a pergunta não esteja bem explicada. Me confirme para eu tentar ajustar ou remover a resposta.

```
Dim ItemsCopy As Integer = 0
Dim Caminho As String = ContarItems(I)
Dim SplitCam As String() = Regex.Split(Caminho.ToString, "=")
//tem que pegar um elemento específico (índice 1 é o segundo) e não varrer todo o array
Vizualizador.ListBox1.Items.Add(S(1))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/RegExFile.vb).

Comment: sim esta certo isso mesmo ai

Comment: Resolveu o problema? Era exatamente isto que você precisava?

Answer (score 0):

Considere mudar seu código para algo que contenha

```
Dim documentos As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
Dim meuArquivoDiretorio As String = "Pasta\Teste\arquivo.teste"

Dim fi = New System.IO.FileInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(documentos, meuArquivoDiretorio))
fi.Directory.Create()

Dim FullFileName As String = fi.FullName
```

Comment: Faça como indiquei acima, que vai funcionar bem, e com mais segurança.

Comment: Trabalhar com nomes de arquivos e diretórios até onde vi não precisa usar Split. É só usar os métodos do Framework. No seu caso, especialmente os métodos do FileInfo

Comment: é mas fileinfo não trabalha da maneira que queria, mas obrigado mesmo assim! ^^

Answer (score 0):

Não! a função corre normalmente sem problema nenhum ele vai exatamente como esta no código, acima deste tem um que simplesmente verifica cada linha da listbox guarda ela no *array*  e passa pra outra função que postei, mas n queria essa primeira parte da string somente a segunda parte como demonstrado no código acima.

```
Dim ContarItems(10) As String
    Dim I As Integer = 0
    Public Sub ExcluirArquivosDesatualizados()
        Dim contar As Integer = Vizualizador.LSTCaminho.Items.Count - 1

        For I = 0 To Vizualizador.LSTCaminho.Items.Count - 1
            Vizualizador.LSTCaminho.SelectedIndex = I

            ContarItems(I) = Vizualizador.LSTCaminho.SelectedItem.ToString
            teste()
        Next


        I = Vizualizador.LSTCaminho.Items.Count - 1
        MsgBox("0 = " & ContarItems(0).ToString & vbNewLine & _
               "1 = " & ContarItems(1))
    End Sub
```

Comment: Isto é uma resposta ou um complemento à pergunta? Você fala português. É muito difícil entender o que você escreve.

Comment: kkkk.. esquece deixa pra la, vou acha um jeito aqui. Mas obrigado por tudo mesmo assim.

Comment: Você quer dizer que a resposta do Tony resolveu o problema? Tente deixar claro (tem links de editar nas suas perguntas e respostas), pois o conteúdo do site não é lido só por você, e sim por milhões de outros usuários que podem chegar nesta pergunta com a mesma dúvida.